# Hybrid code in shell scripts. Sharing variables

Tags: python, bash

I have a shell script which has a piece of python code in it ..
How can I share the `version` variable from my shell script to the piece of python code?

```
#!/bin/sh

version="1"

output=$(python -c '
import sys;
import json;
if $version == 1:
   print("yes")

        ')

echo $output
```

It gives syntax error : Invalid syntax..

Answer (score 5):

Don't share variables. Pass arguments.

```
output=$(python -c '
import sys
if sys.argv[1] == "1":
    print("yes")
' "$version")
```